# trouble with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried get some data from a web service through a AsyncTask But it returns me an empty response and takes a lot of time to connect. Didn't want to put a lot of code here but I think it is the better way to explain what i did.
This is the class that I have implemented to connect.

```
public class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ArrayList<SimpleObserver> listeners;
    private int responseCode;
    private String message;
    private String response;

    public WebService() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<SimpleObserver>();
    }

    public void addListener(SimpleObserver obs) {
        listeners.add(obs);
    }

    public void removeListener(SimpleObserver obs) {
        listeners.remove(obs);
    }

    public void notifyListener(String s) {
        for (SimpleObserver listener : listeners)
            listener.onChange(s);
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        notifyListener("Calculating..");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                notifyListener("Execute");
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
                notifyListener("Chegou aqui");

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        notifyListener(result);
    }
}
```

and to call I used:

```
public class ServiceController implements SimpleObserver {
    private Activity act;
    private WebService s;
    private static final String URL = "my url with parameters";

    public ServiceController(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        act = mainActivity;
        s = new WebService();
        s.addListener(this);
    }

    public void onChange(String s) {
        ((MainActivity) act).getTextView().setText(s);
    }

    public void executeService() {
        try {
            s.execute(new String[] { URL });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I was testing my app that give me this HttpHostConnectException:Connection to 192.168.56.1:8080 refused. 
Locat give me this menssages:

```
08-24 16:58:02.060: W/System.err(17595): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.56.1:8080 refused
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at com.example.pulldata.DS.WebService.doInBackground(WebService.java:68)
08-24 16:58:02.075: W/System.err(17595):    at com.example.pulldata.DS.WebService.doInBackground(WebService.java:1)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-24 16:58:02.080: W/System.err(17595):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.56.1 (port 8080): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-24 16:58:02.085: W/System.err(17595):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595):    ... 15 more
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
08-24 16:58:02.090: W/System.err(17595):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-24 16:58:02.095: W/System.err(17595):    ... 20 more
```

I searched for other question with this problem and all they say it is due to the lack of internet permission but I have that in my manifest! I don't understand at all!

I'm pretty new in android, so can you give me some help?

Comment: Is your SimpleObserver getting the other messages: "Calculating..", "Execute", and "Chegou aqui"? What do you get from the server when you go to the same URL in a browser?

Comment: Yes.. the other menssages are displayed! when I put the URL in a browser it gives me the data!

Comment: Did you add the `users-permission` for using the network/internet? I think it's `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your manifest.

Comment: If you want you can download my code to see!https://gist.github.com/3452164

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your app is making appropriate requests? You should check the status code being returned in your `HTTPResponse` with the methods `getStatusLine()` and `getStatusCode()`. If your requests are correct you should get a 200 back from `getStatusCode()` (which is a `HttpStatus.SC_OK`). Otherwise look at what the request your app is making looks like.

You can find out exactly what your app is sending in it's GET method using a tool like netcat to listen on a port on your PC and have the app connect to that.

If everything looks OK with the request try manually sending it yourself (you can use netcat for this or there is a nice RESTClient debugger plugin for Firefox)

If that shows that you're getting data back, then I suspect that your issue lies in your buffered reader. You can use `Log.d()` statements to print logcat statements showing your string value at various points in your code to see how things progress

Comment: I will try to do that. But I tried manually call directly the webService using a Java Project and It works.  But I will see this.

Comment: I was testing my app that give me this HttpHostConnectException:Connection to http://192.168.56.1:8080 refused. I searched for other question with this problem and all they say it is due to the lack of internet permission but I have that in my manifest! I don't understand at all!

Comment: If you're getting exceptions, you should probably post the contents of logcat.

Comment: I have been post the exceptions! I saw a lot of post searching for an answer but I didn't find it!

Comment: It looks like the machine you're trying to connect to isn't allowing the connection. Try connecting to a site that will guarantee you can connect to it (try www.google.com:80). If that works, then it's something with the site you're connecting to (maybe the wrong port?). If the connection to google.com gets refused then I have a feeling it's an issue with the URL you're passing to HttpGet. I know I once had problems with passing in just a URL, and I ended up having to create a URI with the separate parts (protocol, host, path) and then get a URL from that

Comment: I will try that. and then I tell you something! Thanks! Can you show how did you do it? the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the steps below will help you.

## 1

If the permission to **internet** has been granted in the manifest then problem is that you may not be in the network the host( 192.168.56.1:8080) is in...so try to connect to same network..for eg: i am supposing that to be a private wifi so connect to that network and switch your **packet data** off. so now you'll be able to connect to it.

## 2

Or if you want to connect to it via some other network then you must go on that host( 192.168.56.1:8080) and and ask your network admin to make it a public url so that you can hit it from anywhere.

i hope it helps you.